# Некорректная работа админ панели Django чере Nginx Unit

Tags: python, django

Сервер Debian 10.5
Установлены Nginx Unit + Nginx + Django
Проблема в некорректном отображении админ панели при работе через сервер приложение Nginx Unit. При этом основаня стартовая страница работает норм.

Если запустить встроенный локальный сервер, то все отображается корректно
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но если  использовать через Nginx Unit, то отображается так
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот конфиг Unit

```
{
    "listeners": {
        "*:8501": {
            "pass": "routes"
        }
    },

    "routes": [
        {
            "match": {
                "uri": "/static/*"
            },

            "action": {
                "share": "/var/www/django/aishka.ru/aishkaproject/"
            }
        },
        {
            "action": {
                "pass": "applications/aishka"
            }
        }
    ],

    "applications": {
        "aishka": {
            "type": "python 3.7",
            "path": "/var/www/django/aishka.ru/aishkaproject/",
            "home": "/var/www/django/aishka.ru/venv/",
            "module": "aishkaproject.wsgi",
        }
    }
}
```

Подскажите что я делаю не так? Куда капнуть?

Comment: Вы не раздаете статику. Укажите NGINX откуда раздавать статику (`STATIC_ROOT`), и смотрите, чтобы `STATIC_URL` совпадал со значением в `settings.py`

Comment: В settings.py каталог по умолчанию для статики указан STATIC_URL = '/static/'. Ну и в самом конфиге Unit так же указан как "uri": "/static/*"

Comment: `STATIC_URL` -  не каталог для статики. Каталог для статики -  `STATIC_ROOT`. Попробуйте еще `./manage.py collectstatics`